# Where can I find information about women who worked in French military brothels in WW1?

Tags: france, world-war-one, resource, sexuality

Although I have found memoirs from serving men who used brothels, I cannot find equivalent first hand accounts from the women.

Comment: It might be a good idea to document what you've already found from those memoirs. As for "equivalent", I would think it's very unlikely you'll find prostitutes writing memoirs about their time working in brothels due to the social stigma.